# Sticky footer covers content

Tags: html, css

I have the problem that the content hides behind the footer. I saw if I change the position from fixed tot inherit it helps, but the footer will be at the bottom of the page. I want to see the footer at all times and only be able to scroll the body content.

We are using AngularJS and Bootstrap

[image: image explaining my problem]

Comment: You are a part of Kingsman or the NSA ?

Comment: _“First of all I can't share any code, because this is a "secret" project”_ - so your options are, either you solve it internally and “in secret” as well; or you provide a [mcve] - content anonymized where necessary. (Or, of course, you can go and hire someone that will sign an NDA ...)

Comment: Don't forget that all what you are using is free and open source .. so there is no secret to show HTML/CSS code

Comment: I'm just an intern at a random company. They need a new website and I needed to sign a confidentiality contract.

Comment: You are sending all JS code to user when your website is online, so there's no use in hiding.

Comment: As you see in the answers people can just help me without me sending any code because it is solved.

Comment: and by putting a screenshot of the project isn't risky ?? your company may be upset about this as we can see the layout of the site !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must give your body a `margin-bottom` of `x` pixels, where `x` is the height of the footer (more or less).

Comment: better use `padding-bottom`  instead of `margin-bottom` as and when you are setting any background to your content/body.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting you **sticky footer's height** as `padding-bottom` to your **last content div**, which helps to show your content. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.last-content{  
  margin-top:500px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">Some content goes here
    <div class="last-content">
      you last content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    sticky footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** , Measure your footer height. **Then** add that footer height as `padding-bottom` to your body.
Suppose your footer's height is 100px then add following:

```
body{
  padding-bottom:100px;
}
```

Or you can also add blank div to bottom of you page which will contain same as footer height.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a site I built from [SB-Admin](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/). One detail I left out was to put the sticky-footer class on the body tag. I had also left off the fixed-nav class as well, but I think that's unrelated. After adding the sticky-footer class on my body tag, the footer worked correctly.

So, it should look something like:

```
<body class="sticky-footer">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
      Body content...

    <footer class="sticky-footer">
      Footer content...

    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```